# How to add category base prefix to wordpress permalink

Tags: posts, permalinks, url-rewriting

I tried many solutions provided in many thread but can't figure how to get this working ...

I'd like my post to have a full "silo" structure based on the category prefix set on admin panel (Settings>Permalinks).

Assuming I've set "news" as category base I'd like to have the following structure for my posts and categories :

- website.com/news/
- website.com/news/category-1
- website.com/news/category-1/subcategory-1/
- website.com/news/category-1/subcategory-1/post-title

I tried to use the following code in functions.php :

```
function set_post_permalinks( $post_link, $post ){
    if ( is_object( $post ) && $post->post_type == 'post' ){
        $prefix = get_option( 'category_base' );
        $post_link = $prefix .'/'. $post_link;
    }
    return $post_link;
}
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'set_post_permalinks', 1, 3 );
```

But this isn't working and my posts still got the following structure :

- website.com/category-1/subcategory-1/post-title

If any ideas, as the site already exists, is there a way to 301 redirect all

- website.com/category-1/subcategory-1/post-title

to

- website.com/news/category-1/subcategory-1/post-title

Comment: Why don't you set the category base in the permalink settings? If it doesn't work that way, there is most likely some plugin interfering with the functionality.

Comment: As I said it is already set in permalink settings but the prefix is removed from posts permalink but is present in categories and subcategories, I'll investigate

Comment: Have you also tried using [`post_link`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/post_link) or [`the_permalink`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_permalink) filters?

Comment: I can add my prefix using post_link but this results in a 404. Thanks for your help

Comment: I just tested seeting up the post permalink to `/news/%category%/%postname%/` and it just works.

Comment: It kind of works but it doesn't. It adds a "category" prefix between news and category name. If you use yoast to remove it, it works for post and categories but subcategories doesn't work anymore :/

Comment: @Amandine Hi, could you find a solution?